# Required to join three db tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables as below .

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
    `attendance_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `attendence_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `employee_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`attendance_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=108 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=latin1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `ctc_master` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `employee_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `year` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ctc` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Data as follows

attendance table

| attendance_id | attendence_date | status | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-29 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-30 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-01-29 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2023-01-30 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 2023-01-29 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 2023-01-30 | 0 | 3 |
| 7 | 2023-01-29 | 1 | 4 |
| 8 | 2023-01-30 | 1 | 4 |

employees table

| id | active |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

ctc_master

| id | employee_id | year | ctc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023 | 1000000.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023 | 800000.00 |
| 3 | 3 | 2023 | 150000.00 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022 | 1000000.00 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022 | 800000.00 |
| 6 | 3 | 2022 | 150000.00 |

Tried the below query to get all the employees and the count when attendance status  = 1  between the time periods.

```
select count(*) , employee_id from attendance atd where status = 1 and 
attendence_date between '2022-10-01'  and '2022-10-30' group by employee_id ;
```

I need to join above three tables to fetch employee_id, ctc , count of attendance status

```
select ctc.employee_id, ctc.ctc , ctc.year from  employees emp  
join ctc_master_tbl ctc on  emp.id = ctc.employee_id  
join attendance atd on emp.id = atd.employee_id 
and emp.id  = atd.employee_id and  emp.id = ctc.employee_id  where emp.active =1 and  
atd.attendence_date between '2022-01-28'  and '2022-01-31' ;
```

expected output would be

```
employee_id , year of the attendence_date ,count of status of each employee where status =1 , ctc.
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output? Also what's the association between the sample table values and field names?

Comment: make your expected value to be table

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you need to add year to the join between attendance and ctc_master and then group by the non-aggregated fields in your select list -

```
select ctc.employee_id, ctc.ctc , ctc.year, SUM(status = 1) as present, SUM(status = 0) as absent
from  employees emp  
join ctc_master ctc
    on  emp.id = ctc.employee_id 
join attendance atd
    on emp.id = atd.employee_id
    and ctc.year = year(atd.attendence_date)
where emp.active = 1
and atd.attendence_date between '2022-01-28'  and '2022-01-31'
group by emp.id, ctc.year, ctc.ctc;
```

If you add the "missing" unique index on ctc_master (employee_id, year) then you will no longer need `ctc.ctc` in the group by list.